# Is there a way to get value from different dataframe cell based on current dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

As given in the below example.
I am trying to find the operator logout time.

I have one source, with each truck operator login timestamp.

Another source, with truck operator logout timestamp (In this source, logout timestamp is not associated with the operator)

here is a sample source

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import (DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType, ArrayType, MapType, TimestampType, LongType)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

columns1 = ["truck","operator","firstlogin","lead_login","firstlogin_unix","leadlogin_unix"]
data1 = [("t1","1", "2023-06-02T00:17:02.095+0000", "2023-06-02T01:57:31.868+0000",1685665022,1685671051),
    ("t1","2", "2023-06-02T01:57:31.868+0000","2023-06-02T02:25:55.484+0000",1685671051,1685672755),
    ("t1","3", "2023-06-02T02:25:55.484+0000","2023-06-02T13:56:47.373+0000",1685672755,1685714207),
    ("t1","1", "2023-06-02T13:56:47.373+0000","2023-06-02T23:53:39.829+0000",1685714207,1685750019),
    ("t1","4", "2023-06-02T23:53:39.829+0000",None,1685750019,None),
    ("t2","A", "2023-06-02T14:00:00.373+0000","2023-06-02T23:53:39.829+0000",1685714418,1685750019)]

df_op_login = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=columns1)

df_op_login = df_op_login.select(
    col('truck'),col('operator'),col('firstlogin'),col('lead_login'),
    col('firstlogin_unix').cast(LongType()),col('leadlogin_unix').cast(LongType())
)

df_op_login.show(truncate=False)


columns2 = ["truck","log_out_ts","log_out_unix_ts"]
data2 = [("t1","2023-06-02T00:02:50.242000",1685664170),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T01:50:42.436000",1685670642),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T01:53:31.231000",1685670811),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T02:00:27.855000",1685671227),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T02:46:20.058000",1685673980),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T05:57:15.370000",1685685435),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T06:06:30.526000",1685685990),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T06:15:16.062000",1685686516),
    ("t1","2023-06-02T10:26:53.795000",1685701613),    
    ("t1","2023-06-02T10:33:43.012000",1685702023),
    ("t2","2023-06-02T15:35:43.012000",1685720143)]

df_op_logout = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=columns2)

df_op_logout = df_op_logout.select(
    col('truck'),col('log_out_ts'),col('log_out_unix_ts').cast(LongType())
)

df_op_logout.show(truncate=False)
```

Now I created a UDF to get logout timestamp based timestamp between "firstlogin_unix" and "leadlogin_unix". But I am blocked with error **cannot resolve '`firstlogin_unix`' given input columns: [log_out_ts, log_out_unix_ts, truck];**

```
w =  Window.partitionBy("truck")

def get_logout(x, y, z):  
  df_op_logout_tmp = (
      df_op_logout
      .filter(col('truck') == x)
      .filter(col('log_out_unix_ts') >= y)
      .filter(col('log_out_unix_ts') <= z)
      .withColumn('max_ts', sf.max('log_out_unix_ts').over(w))
      .filter(sf.col('log_out_unix_ts') == sf.col('max_ts') )
  )
  if df_op_logout_tmp.count() > 0:
    return df_op_logout_tmp.collect()[0]['log_out_ts']
  else:
    return None
  
# get_logout('t1', 1685665022, 1685671051)

df_op_final = (
    df_op_login
    # .withColumn('op_logout',sf.lit(get_logout('t1', 1685665022, 1685671051)))
    .withColumn('op_logout',sf.lit(get_logout(col('truck'), col('firstlogin_unix'), col('leadlogin_unix'))))
)

display(df_op_final)
```

Expected output:

[image]

Logic (follow color code):
One Truck can be operated by different operators.
For a given truck, I am trying to find logout timestamp based on login timestamp and new operator login(lead_login)

[image]

**But I am blocked with error cannot resolve 'firstlogin_unix' given input columns: [log_out_ts, log_out_unix_ts, truck];**

Comment: @murtihash request your help

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

 # Create DataFrames
df_op_login = spark.createDataFrame(data1, schema=columns1)
df_op_logout = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema=columns2)

# Create a window
w = Window.partitionBy("truck")

# Define a UDF to get the logout timestamp
def get_logout(x, y, z):
    df_op_logout_tmp = (
    df_op_logout
    .filter(col('truck') == x)
    .filter(col('log_out_unix_ts') >= y)
    .filter(col('log_out_unix_ts') <= z)
    .withColumn('max_ts', max('log_out_unix_ts').over(w))
    .filter(col('log_out_unix_ts') == col('max_ts') )
    )
    if df_op_logout_tmp.count() > 0:
        return df_op_logout_tmp.collect()[0]['log_out_ts']
    else:
        return None

# Apply the UDF
df_op_final = (df_op_login.withColumn('op_logout', udf(get_logout, TimestampType())(col('truck'), col('firstlogin_unix'), col('leadlogin_unix'))))

# Display the results
df_op_final.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: No, I am getting 
Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object 
error.

your script also returns same error.

Comment: In which line of my code you are getting error? I'm not using any `pickle` file import in  my code.

Comment: I am running script in azure databricks using PySpark.
Will that make difference ?

Comment: and are you able to get desired output ?